# "Cannot find module 'webpack/hot/log.js'" error when starting React app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, websocket, node-modules, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to run my ReactJS app locally using the `npm start` command. After some time, http://localhost:3000/ opens in Chrome, but nothing appears, only a blank white screen.

I checked the console and saw this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/hot/log.js'
    at webpackMissingModule (WebSocketClient.js:56:1)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10 (WebSocketClient.js:56:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:5:1
    at startup:7:1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you please help with this? any react.js devs are here????

Comment: no one know the answer of this question???

Answer (score 0):

The `npm i webpack --save-dev` should do the trick.